# batch search for windows drive letter, if exists set as variable and execute command, else try another letter

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch file that looks for a drive letter and executes code, otherwise looks for another letter and executes same code. I want to set letter as variable so I don't have to repeat code, something like:

```
if exist E:\ 
var = E:\
else
if exist D:\
var = D:\

mv var\SQL\...\...
del var\...\...
```

Will this logic work? Or is it better to use

```
if exist E:\ goto cont1
else goto newletter

:cont1
code

:newletter
if exist D:\ go to cont2
else goto end

:cont2 
code

:end
```

Comment: I would just use the FOR command to iterate over all possible drive letters.

Answer (score 4):

To get all available drives, you could use the `wmic` command:

```dos
wmic LogicalDisk GET DeviceID
```

You can also filter for certain drive types, like for local disks, for example (consult the Microsoft article [Win32_LogicalDisk class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) for all the possible `DriveType` filter options):

```dos
wmic LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType=3 GET DeviceID
```

Then wrap around two `for /F` loops to get the output of the `wmic` command line (to not filter, simply remove the `WHERE DriveType^=3` portion):

```dos
for /F "skip=1" %%D in ('wmic LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType^=3 GET DeviceID') do (
    for /F %%C in ("%%D") do (
        echo Do stuff with drive %%D\...
    )
)
```

The outer `for /F` loop captures the output of the `wmic` command line. Since `wmic` produces Unicode output which `for /F` has problems with (it leaves some orphaned carriage-return characters in the captured output), another `for /F` loop is nested to get rid of these artefacts.

---

If you do not want to use the `wmic` command for some reason, you could alternatively loop through all letters of the alphabet using a `for` loop and check whether the drive exists, like this:

```dos
for %%D in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
    if exist "%%D:\" (
        echo Do stuff with drive %%D:\...
    )
)
```

Here, no filtering by drive type is possible, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked on my Windows 10 system for detecting drives :

```
@echo off
if not exist c: goto check2
set temp=C
goto sharedcode

:check2
if not exist d: goto error
set temp=D
goto sharedcode

:sharedcode
echo %temp%:\ exists!
goto end

:error
echo nothing exists!

:end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should only iterate your mounted drives in reverse order;

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "DELIMS=\" %%A IN ('MOUNTVOL^|FIND ":\"') DO CALL SET _=%%A %%_%%
FOR %%A IN (%_%) DO (ECHO=MV %%A\SQL\...\...
    ECHO=DEL %%A\...\...)
TIMEOUT -1 1>NUL
```

**[EDIT /]**

```bat
IF EXIST E:\ (SET drive=E:) ELSE (IF EXIST D:\ (SET drive=D:) ELSE (ECHO="No E:\ or D:\ drive found"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution to my scenario, since I am only looking for 2 drives, I find an if else statement to work nicely

```
if exist E:\ ( SET drive=E: )
else if exist D:\ ( set drive=D: )
else ( echo "No E:\ or D:\ drive found")
```

This way, I can just set all code after this to a variable %drive% and do not have to repeat any code
Thanks for everyones input

Comment: That code cannot work as intended it is structured and formatted incorrectly. See the [EDIT /] on my answer.